# Elasticsearch: average count of matching nested documents

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have documents with nested items. The mapping is something like the following:

```
"document": {
   "properties": {
       "fieldA": { "type": "integer" },
       "items": { "type": "nested",
                  "properties": {
                     "is_x": {"type": "boolean"},
                     "name": {"type": "string"}
                   }
       }
    }
 }
```

And a sample document:

```
document:
  fieldA: 123,
  ...
  items: 
  [
    { "name": "item1", "is_x":true},
    { "name": "item2", "is_x":false},
      ...
    { "name": "itemn", "is_x":true}
  ]
```

I want to get the average count of items per document that have `"is_x"=false`

One option is to save this value during the indexing, but I would love to know how this can be done during the search itself (search performance is not an issue in this case).